# Python error "Module not found" while trying to read .xls file. How to install xlrd?

Tags: python, installation, pip, conda, xlrd

I was trying to import the xls file where I am getting this error.

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.

Help me resoling this error.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8kYx.png)

Guidance in how to use pip or conda to install xlrd.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImportError%3A+Missing+optional+dependency+xlrd

Answer (score 1):

You have not downloaded `xlrd` module.
Python has certain modules and libraries that need to be installed on top of the built-in packages. For installing modules using pip, use the syntax `pip install [module_name]` where you can also put the version number(optional) specifically required for your usage with `[module_name]==[version_no]`

Try using `pip install xlrd==1.1.0`. That will install your module in your local Python system.

If you want details, the documentation for this module can be found here :

For latest version (2.0.1) - https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/

For your required version (1.1.0) - https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/1.1.0/

Answer (score 0):

You missed the dependency, below is the command to install it.

pip install xlrd